# Is there a way to change these autogenerated column names on an ASP.net C# Custom Edit page? Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Thanks for reading my Q! I'm currently completing a degree in ICT and for my final year project I'm creating a web application using C#, ASP.Net and a back end MS SQL Database.

For my project I'm looking to remove these auto generated column names on this formview from my edit page.

E.G.

Where it says name, I'd like it to say "Full Name", gender > "Gender", houseNo > "House Number" and so on...

Is this possible? I'm sure it is but I've come to a halt with progression!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gbiI.png

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data anotations like this

```
[Display(Name = "House Number")]
int houseNo {get; set;}
```

in your models